# How to get logging working in Nginxinc's Ansible role in the playbook directly?

Tags: nginx, logging, ansible

I installed Nginxinc's Ansible role directly from Github, using the Ansible Galaxy and I do not get the logging working directly in the playbook. I tried several methodologies to get my custom logging format to work, but all of which failed, still the log file's name and format are different to my custom one.
Here is my playbook, simplified:

```
- name: Install NGINX and configure a simple reverse proxy in front of a web server
  hosts: "{{ host }}"
  become: true
  collections:
    - nginxinc.nginx_core
  tasks:
    - name: Install NGINX
      include_role:
        name: nginx
    - name: Configure NGINX
      include_role:
        name: nginx_config
      vars:
        nginx_config_http_template_enable: true
        log:  # Configure logs
          format:
            - name: main
              escape: default
              format: |
                '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
          access:
            - path: /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log
              format: main
              if: $loggable
          error:
            file: /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log
            level: notice
            format: main
        nginx_config_http_template:
          - template_file: http/default.conf.j2
            deployment_location: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            config:
              upstreams:
                - name: upstr
                  least_conn: true
                  servers:
                    - address: 0.0.0.0:8089
              servers:
                - core:
                    listen ssl http2:
                      - port: 443
                        ssl_certificate: /etc/letsencrypt/live/service.company.com/fullchain.pem
                        ssl_certificate_key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/service.company.com/privkey.pem
                  locations:
                    - location: /bladash_test/dashboard_test
```

What am I missing? I'm very thankful for any hint!

I tried several places and locations, like in the playbook as stated above and in a template, but nothing seemed to work.
I expected my custom format for logging and log file's name to work as stated in the code above.

EDIT:

After digging into it again I've just found this defaults file where the logging is configured (at least in this molecule example): https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-role-nginx-config/blob/main/molecule/common/files/nginx.conf
Where can I override it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> and in a template

[Ansible roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#roles) are designed for reusability - that's their main goal. Overridable variables are defined in `defaults` folder (it's also stated in the role's [README file](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-role-nginx-config/blob/main/README.md#role-variables)). Generally, you don't change anything but these variables to configure a role. For example, there you can [find](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-role-nginx-config/blob/main/defaults/main/template.yml#L639):

```yaml
# ...

# Enable creating dynamic templated NGINX HTTP configuration files.
# Defaults will not produce a valid configuration. Instead they are meant to showcase
# the options available for templating. Each dictionary in the top level list/array represents a new configuration file.
# Unless otherwise noted, all variables are *strings* and *optional* (*required* values inside a dictionary are only required if the top level variable is defined).
# Most (not all) of these directives can also be used under the 'server' and 'location' contexts, as briefly seen at the end of the below dictionary.
nginx_config_http_template_enable: false
nginx_config_http_template:
  - template_file: http/default.conf.j2
    deployment_location: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    backup: true
    config:
    # ...
      log:  # Configure logs
        format:  # Available only in the 'http' context
          - name: main  # Required
            escape: default  # Can be set to 'default', 'json' or 'none'
            format: |  # Required
              '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
```

Based on that, there are the following errors in your example:

- you've defined the `log` dict on the wrong level - it should have been defined as a key in `nginx_config_http_template[0].config` dict instead;
- `listen ssl http2` is not a valid key. It's probably just a copy-paste issue but still - `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` are not keys of any of `listen`, `ssl`, or `http2` dicts - they could belong to either `proxy` or `grpc`.

So, something like this should work - at least it's valid from the role configuration perspective (not sure about NGINX itself). I've also removed the keys that are not marked as required as per the comments:

```yaml
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Configure NGINX
      ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: ansible-role-nginx-config
      vars:
        nginx_config_http_template_enable: true
        nginx_config_http_template:
          - config:
              upstreams:
                - name: upstr
                  least_conn: true
                  servers:
                    - address: 0.0.0.0:8089
              servers:
                - core:
                    listen:
                      - port: 443
                  ssl:
                    certificate: /etc/letsencrypt/live/service.company.com/fullchain.pem
                    certificate_key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/service.company.com/privkey.pem
                  locations:
                    - location: /bladash_test/dashboard_test
              log:
                format:
                  - name: main
                    escape: default
                    format: |
                      '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
                access:
                  - path: /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log
                    format: main
                    if: $loggable
                error:
                  file: /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log
                  level: notice
                  format: main
```

By the way -  don't use `hosts: "{{ host }}"`. It barely makes your playbook reusable; in fact, it makes things worse and prevents you from using [inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) (thus, defining the variables per host or per group(s) of hosts). If you want to run the play locally, use `hosts: localhost`. If you want to run the play on the target group of hosts, define it in the inventory and set `hosts: your_target_group`, or `all` if you want to run it everywhere. You can always restrict the target hosts by setting [`--limit host1,host2,group3` CLI argument](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ad-hoc-commands) instead of passing a custom variable like `host`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will try to get my script working based on your suggestions. I really appreciate that!